# Memory specification error when submitting a job with sbatch

Tags: slurm

I am trying to submit a job with the `sbatch` command and getting the following error:

```
sbatch --mem-per-cpu=1024 -N2  -n 2 --job-name="test" -p partition script
sbatch: error: Memory specification can not be satisfied
sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Requested node configuration is not available
```

It says `Memory specification can not be satisfied` although I have much more free memory available in the cluster.

Comment: Do you have any active nodes in your Slurm cluster?

Comment: yes ,i have a lot of active nodes

Comment: You should provide more information, ie. output from `sinfo`, config file with node definitions etc.